# Function and argument unmarshalling in go?

Tags: go

Given an interface containing functions with varying parameters and a concrete implementation of that interface how do I take a stream of bytes and call methods from the interface based on that byte stream.  Basically an RPC call.

e.g.

```
type funcs interface {
  func Hello(name string) (string, error)
  func Add(numbers...int) (result, error)
}
```

And lets say I had the following input data

```
Hello John
Add 1 2 3 4
```

I figure this has to be done with reflection but this package I find a bit of mystery to use.  Not great examples.  Looking at RPC packages is also a bit mysterious. I don't understand what they are doing and there seem to be limitations or assumptions, perhaps to make the code simpler and/or faster to implement.

Can someone shed some light on how I might take the string "Hello" and find the function handle "Hello" from the funcs table.  And know that it's expecting a single parameter that is a string and then calling that function with the argument provided "John".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `reflect` package (general caveats about performance and code readability apply).  Just create a type and implement the functions for that type, then call [reflect.MethodByName()](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MethodByName) on a `Value` created from an instance of that type:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type functions struct {}

func (f functions) Hello(name string) (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("Hello,", name)
    return name, nil
}

func main() {
    var f functions
    m := reflect.ValueOf(f).MethodByName("Hello")
    if m.IsValid() {
        // Either call f.Hello() here, or use the returned Value like so:
        v := make([]reflect.Value, 1) // function Values only take Value slices as arguments
        v[0] = reflect.ValueOf("Asha")
        r := m.Call(v)
        fmt.Println("Returned", r)
    }
}
```

This prints:

`Hello, Asha
Returned [Asha <error Value>]`

(See https://play.golang.org/p/0q1i3WBuAL)

However, if you know the function names you want to be able to call *a priori*, or if you want the user to be able to use names other than the exact function name, just use a `switch` or `if`/`else` statement:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func Hello(name string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello,", name)
}

func main() {
    userInput := make([]string, 2)
    userInput[0] = "HeLlO"
    userInput[1] = "재은"

    switch(strings.ToLower(userInput[0])) { // allow any case
    case "hello":
        Hello(userInput[1])
    default:
        panic("user input not recognized")
    }
}
```

This prints:

`Hello, 재은`

(See https://play.golang.org/p/oBxsI42q4a)

Comment: Thanks this looks like the missing piece of the puzzle.  MethodByName and example usage.